# Brezis' exercise 6.20.3: give an explicit formula for $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $E$ be a real Banach space. Let $\mathcal L(E)$ be the space of bounded linear operators on $E$ and $\mathcal K(E)$ its subspace consisting of compact operators. Let $I:E \to E$ be the identity map. For $T \in \mathcal L(E)$,

- we denote by $N(T)$ its kernel and by $R(T)$ its range.
- we denote by $\rho(T)$ its [resolvent set](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1345626/368425), by $\sigma(T)$ its spectrum, and by $EV(T)$ its set of eigenvalues. Then $EV(T) \subset \sigma(T) = \mathbb R \setminus \rho(T)$.
- for $\lambda \in EV(T)$, the set $N(T-\lambda I)$ is called the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda$.

I'm trying to solve an exercise in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> Let $E=L^p(0,1)$ with $1 \leq p<\infty$. Given $u \in E$, set
> $$
> T u(x) = \int_0^x u(t) \, d t .
> $$
>
> 1. Prove that $T \in \mathcal{K}(E)$.
> 2. Determine $E V(T)$ and $\sigma(T)$.
> 3. Give an explicit formula for $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$ when $\lambda \in \rho(T)$.
> 4. Determine $T^{\star}$.

There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in below attempt of (3). Could you please have a check on it? I'm also happy to see other approaches.

---

Let $v \in E$. We look for $u\in E$ such that $(T-\lambda I)u=v$. Let $y:=Tu$. By Lebesgue differentiation [theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4610584/a-simple-proof-of-lebesgue-differentiation-theorem-for-dimension-1), $y$ is differentiable a.e. and $y'=u$ a.e. Let $\mu := -\frac{1}{\lambda}$. Then $y' + \mu y = \mu v$ a.e.  By [theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2103529/368425) of ODE, we assume $y$ has a form $y (t) = K(t) e^{-\mu t}$ for some function $K$ we are looking for. Then $y' (t) = K'(t) e^{-\mu t} - \mu K(t) e^{-\mu t}$. Then $y' + \mu y = \mu v$ implies $K'(t) e^{-\mu t} = \mu v(t)$. Then $K'(t) = \mu v(t) e^{\mu t}$. Intuitively, we define
$$
K(x) := \mu \int_0^x v(t) e^{\mu t} \, dt.
$$

Then
$$
\begin{align*}
u (x) &= y'(x) \\
&= K'(x) e^{-\mu x} - \mu K(x) e^{-\mu x} \\
&= \mu v(x) - \mu^2 e^{-\mu x} \int_0^x v(t) e^{\mu t} \, dt \\
&= \mu v(x) - \mu^2 \int_0^x v(t) e^{\mu (t-x)} \, dt.
\end{align*}
$$